# How to change Flutter Desktop cursor pointer?

Tags: macos, flutter, flutter-desktop

I want to change the cursor pointer on hover a certain widget, but I can't find how to achieve this.

Looking to this [comment](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/issues/376#issuecomment-637853413) seems like they already have it for macOS, but I can't find anything about how to implement.

How can I change my cursor on hover a widget?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a `cursor` property on `MouseRegion`, which controls what cursor is shown when the pointer is in the region. For instance:

```
MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
  child: YourWidgetHere(),
)
```

Comment: Does this mean that any time you want to change the cursor you need to rebuild all the subwidgets?

Comment: @Gerard not necessarily, it could be like AnimatedBuilder where child is not rebuilt. however I have no confirmation

Comment: Thanks, for Flutter web this means links without Stateful Wiget.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the mouse cursor with a custom widget, you could also follow this [article](https://dev.to/iamsahdeep/custom-cursor-in-flutter-web-1k4l).

In summary:

1. Use a MouseRegion to hide the real cursor but still save its position with onHover
2. Use a Stack and Positioned/AnimatedPositioned widget to add your custom cursor on top of the widget

```dart
// Use a stateful widget to record the cursor position
Offset position;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MouseRegion(
    cursor: SystemMouseCursors.none,
    onHover: (event) {
      setState(() {
        // Save the position of the cursor when it moves
        position = event.position; 
      });
    },
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        MyWidget(),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          left: position.dx,
          top: position.dy,
          child: CustomCursor(),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ),
}
```